# ECC Corrected, Realloc Events, Seek Errors, etc. in Spinrite 6

Tags: hard-drive, spinrite

I am running [SpinRite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpinRite) 6 on a dying hard drive. What do all these terms mean on the SMART Monitor screen?

- ECC Corrected
- Realloc Events
- Seek Errors
- Recal Retrires
- Cabling Errors
- Uncorrectable
- Write Errors

[image]

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of this page...http://www.grc.com/sroverview.htm.. if the info is not in any of those links, contact the author Steve Gibson.

Comment: ^ Thanks but the site doesn't list any info about it. I'll look into contacting the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like those are abbreviations of [S.M.A.R.T. attribute names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes).

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

- ECC Corrected - The sector was read multiple times and was recovered by combining the different results.
- Realloc Events - Sectors that were reallocated elsewhere.
- Seek Errors - Sectors that could not be reached (the seek failed)
- Recal Retries - How many attempts to recalibrate were made.
- Cabling Errors - Errors due to the interference (noise in the cables?)
- Uncorrectable - Sectors that could not be recovered
- Write Errors - Sectors that gave an error when written (Spinrite --depending on the configured mode-- first reads the sector, then writes it again, making sure it's still in good health)

Comment: With ECC you should not need to read multiple times. Assuming single/few bit errors you can correct with a single reading. FOr a very simple example how corrections occur see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/381875/ecc-registered-vs-ecc-unbuffered).